# good mysql class for php website?

Tags: php, mysql, class

I was using [ezmysql](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/790-PHP-Makes-using-mySQL-ridiculously-easy-great-docs-.html) class initially for mysql operations, but that is not updated.

So i want to know is there any ***easy and well documented mysql class*** which can be used to develop my php website?

Thanks.

Comment: the 1st two answers compliment each other and both get +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers suggested using [**MySQLi**](https://www.php.net/mysqli) -- which is a good solution.

Another good solution would be working with [**PDO**](http://fr.php.net/pdo) *(which supports MySQL, of course, but also helps working with other DB engines)*.

Else, if you need a more complex *(but powerful, once you know it)* system, you could go with an ORM layer, such as [**Doctrine**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [**Propel**](http://www.propelorm.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to the popular "Don't reinvent the wheel" wisdom, I would really suggest writing your own DB abstraction class if the built in stuff like aforementioned MySQLi class doesn't suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

[MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), it the default mysql class libary..

Comment: @Trcker, thanks for that, but i need to debug also..thats why i like `ezmySQL` class

Answer (score 0):

Go for PDO. Although PDO is harder to learn. But  is more secure and more portable. I use it myself, here's a sample query

```
try {
$id = 1;
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->hostname;dbname=test", $this->username, $this->password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRORMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=:id");
//note that you need your variables set before you can bind it.
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
$stmt->execute();
//similar to $mysqli->fetchAll()
$stmt->fetchAll();
} catch(Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Hopefully you like how PDO works.. it is more secure for your queries. Additionally you can use PDO for Updating and Inserting queries too.

Here's some tutorial for you to start using PDO: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/